# Drag And Drop Not Working In ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

My problem is the drag and drop of border become not workin when I wrap the canvas inside the scrollviewer.

1200x1200 canvas put in the 500x500 scrollviewer. I want the canvas is scrollable (touch slide) in the scrollviewer. The drag and drop in canvas is working perfectly before I insert in the scrollviewer.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="True">
        <ScrollViewer Name="scbb" Width="500" Height="500" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="LightBlue" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="1200" Height="1200"
            MouseLeftButtonDown="CanvasMouseLeftButtonDown"
            MouseLeftButtonUp="CanvasMouseLeftButtonUp"
            MouseMove="CanvasMouseMove">
        </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button x:Name="btnEnable" Content="Enable" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,115,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="btnEnable_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Add Image" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="AddButtonClick" Margin="0,0,10,10"/>
    </Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void AddButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int iNum = SETTING.GetTableRunningNumber();

            var borderWrap = new Border();
            borderWrap.Width = 100;
            borderWrap.Height = 100;
            borderWrap.Background = Brushes.Green;

            var label1 = new Label();
            label1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label1.Content = "Table " + iNum.ToString();
            label1.Name = "Table" + iNum.ToString();
            label1.Foreground = Brushes.White;
            label1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

            borderWrap.Child = label1;
            borderWrap.MouseDown += TableMouseDown;

            Canvas.SetLeft(borderWrap, 10);
            Canvas.SetTop(borderWrap, 10);
            canvas.Children.Add(borderWrap);

            iNum += 1;
            SETTING.SetTableRunningNumber(iNum);
        }

        private Point mousePosition;
        private Border draggedBorder;

        private void TableMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!SETTING.GetEnableDrag())
            {
                var cLabel = e.Source as Label;
                var bBorder = e.Source as Border;

                if (cLabel != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(cLabel.Name.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private void CanvasMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SETTING.GetEnableDrag())
            {
                var dBorder = e.Source as Border;
                var cLabel = e.Source as Label;

                if (dBorder == null)
                {
                    dBorder = (Border)cLabel.Parent;
                }

                if (dBorder != null && canvas.CaptureMouse())
                {
                    mousePosition = e.GetPosition(canvas);
                    draggedBorder = dBorder;
                    Panel.SetZIndex(draggedBorder, 1);
                }
            }           
        }

        async Task PutTaskDelay100()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

        private async void CanvasMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SETTING.GetEnableDrag())
            {
                await PutTaskDelay100();
                if (draggedBorder != null)
                {
                    canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                    Panel.SetZIndex(draggedBorder, 0);
                    draggedBorder = null;
                }

            }
        }

        private void CanvasMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SETTING.GetEnableDrag())
            {
                double canvasSize = 1200;
                if (draggedBorder != null)
                {
                    var position = e.GetPosition(canvas);
                    var offset = position - mousePosition;
                    mousePosition = position;

                    double newTop = Canvas.GetTop(draggedBorder) + offset.Y;
                    double newLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(draggedBorder) + offset.X;

                    if (newTop < 0)
                    {
                        newTop = 0;
                    }
                    else if (newTop + draggedBorder.ActualWidth > canvasSize)
                        newTop = canvasSize - draggedBorder.ActualWidth;

                    if (newLeft < 0)
                    {
                        newLeft = 0;
                    }
                    else if (newLeft + draggedBorder.ActualWidth > canvasSize)
                        newLeft = canvasSize - draggedBorder.ActualWidth;

                    Canvas.SetLeft(draggedBorder, newLeft);
                    Canvas.SetTop(draggedBorder, newTop);
                }
            }       
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the problem months ago and solved it in the code behind with these additions.

After the InitializeComponent in the WindowMain.xaml.cs add:

```
    public WindowMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // your code, etc.

    scrollViewer.AllowDrop = true;
    scrollViewer.PreviewDragEnter += scrollViewer_PreviewDragEnter;
    scrollViewer.PreviewDragOver += scrollViewer_PreviewDragOver;
    scrollViewer.Drop += scrollViewer_Drop;
}


void scrollViewer_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}

void scrollViewer_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

bool IsDataAvailable = false;
void scrollViewer_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Get data object
    var dataObject = e.Data as DataObject;

    // Check for file list
    if (dataObject.ContainsFileDropList())
    {
        // Process file names
        StringCollection fileNames = dataObject.GetFileDropList();
        bool isIsDataAvailable = false;
        try
        {
            var uri = new Uri(fileNames[0]);
            BitmapSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
            isIsDataAvailable = true;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            string errorMessage = error.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            IsDataAvailable = isIsDataAvailable;
        }
    }
}
```

My program just loads a dropped file from the explorer file list I drop on the ScrollViewer . The `scbb.AllowDrop=true` in the ScrollViewer has to be set. And the routines to handle basic drag and drop. Your code should work once the ScrollViewer allows dropping.

Comment: Thanks bro, currently my code the drag and drop is done in the canvas. While the 1200x1200 canvas put in the 500x500 scrollviewer. i want the canvas is scrollable (touch slide) in the scrollviewer.

Comment: Ok, Once you added the Canvas to the ScrollViewer, it did not work. The ScrollViewer is not enabled for drop, add scbb.AllowDrop=true in the:<ScrollViewer x:Name="scbb" AllowDrop="true" />